# Can't delete laravel storage cache folder

Tags: laravel, directory, storage, file-permissions

I am new in Laravel.

I am trying to delete the data folder which is under `/storage/framework/cache/`.

I did `php artisan cache:clear` which produces: `Application cache cleared!`

But when I go into the directory `/storage/framework/cache/data` then I see the old cache folders are still there and when I try to delete the folder manually then I get permission issue.

I have followed the below thread to give permissions to the storage folder.

[How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

Permission level -

```
drwxrwsr-x   7  ubuntu   www-data 4096 Apr 24 22:48 storage
   drwxrwxr-x   7  ubuntu   www-data 4096 Apr 28 16:57 framework
     drwxrwxr-x   4  ubuntu   www-data 4096 Apr 29 18:32 cache
        drwxrwxr-x   39 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 29 20:36 data
```

I am logged in as a user `subadmin` who is under `www-data` group. I can though delete the folder manually after login as user `ubuntu` but not as `subadmin`

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What permission error message do you get? Furthermore your directory list shows that all folders are on the same level. Normally, it is `storage/framework/cache`. There seems some folders are not correctly in place.

Comment: @codedge I get permission denied when I try to delete any folder under data. Sorry for the folder structure here but it is correct as you said ie `storage/framework/cache` in original project directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to delete `cache/data` directory?

I believe that folder is the part of default directory, of laravel

Default Stucture:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/storage/framework/cache

Which I believe by default is used by:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/cache.php#L53

If you want to make sure that your clear cache command works see the content of the data directory,

Comment: On your file permsision issue, are you sure `subadmin` is in `www-data` group?

Comment: Yes subadmin is in www-data group. I also checked the contents of data folder after I issue the command `php artisan cache:clear` and the cache is still there. I actually wanted to delete the contents of `cache/data` directory.

Comment: What's the permission of the cache file?

Comment: Hmm that seems off to me, What about the configuration, do you have the right configuration? and are you sure the cached configuration is the one pointed to right cache dir?

Comment: How can I check if the cached configuration is pointing to right cache dir? The permission of cache folder under data directory is - `drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Apr 29 17:31 19` Anything under data folder is owned by www-data

Comment: No, I mean the cache file under the `cache/data` directory, not the directory

Comment: To check the configuration, you can go to this file in your project, https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/cache.php#L34 , check whether the  `stores` key member has the right configuration. If so, go to `<your_app_dir>/bootstrap/cache/config.php`, check whether the same key is value is correct, if it's not correct, you can regenerate your cahce using `php artisan config:cache` (make sure  to use it with the right user though, otherwise your web server can't read it)

Comment: There are several directories under data. For eg one of the folder name is `d7`and under d7 there is another folder `1a` and under this folder the file is - `d71abc6f5c2b4b9af7089bfcf1d25e27447697e4`.The permission is `-rwxrwxr-- 1 www-data www-data 8902 Apr 29 17:31 d71abc6f5c2b4b9af7089bfcf1d25e27447697e4`

Comment: OK the file looks good to me, be aware that if the web server is running, your app might create a new cache file, make sure the check the new file timestamp or check whether the old cache file is deleted

Comment: Ok thanks. I will check more deeper tomorrow morning.

Comment: I think it's the user `subadmin` who is under `www-data` group has no enough permission to delete the cache/data directory contents which is owned by `www-data`. It's a linux permission issue rather laravel issue but just can't figure out how to let the user subadmin give the permission to delete cache content..

Comment: File deletion permission is based on your directory permission,  check the dir permission that you want to delete, make sure you have `w` in dir permission in group  section, can check whether the result `groups` command executed as `subadmin` has the `www-data` ? Do you enable selinux or apparmor?

Comment: It's fixed now. I had to give the group W permission. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make the current user own everything inside the folder (and the folder itself):

```
sudo chown -R $USER /your/path
```

maybe you would like to do it for the apache folder like what i did

```
sudo chown -R $USER /var/www/
```

this should fix the permissions problem for you

Comment: Thanks. Actually I had to do `sudo chown -R www-data:<group> storage` . The `group` has got the user who has write access to the folder.